# How to define enumerated types in SMT-LIB for Z3

Tags: z3, smt

I previously used Z3's API to define an enumerated type like so

```
let T = ctx.MkEnumSort("T", [| "a"; "b"; "c"|])
```

which enumerates the elements of a type T as being "a" "b" and "c" (and nothing else). However I am now trying to do something similar but via SMT-LIB rather than the API and I am running into a problem of Z3 complaining about quantifiers. The program I am using (Boogie) generates the following smt

```
...
(declare-sort T@T 0)
(declare-fun a() T@T)
(declare-fun b() T@T)
(declare-fun c() T@T)
(assert (forall ((x T@T) ) 
    (! (or
          (= x a)
          (= x b)
          (= x c)
       )
       :qid |gen.28:15|
       :skolemid |1|
     )))
...
```

The assertion is the type closure axiom that asserts that the type has no other members. But when I send this (along with other stuff) to Z3, after thinking about it a bit, returns

```
WARNING: relevacy must be enabled to use option CASE_SPLIT=3, 4 or 5
unknown
(:reason-unknown (incomplete quantifiers))
```

Notes: 1. I have MBQI turned on. 2. Boogie has an option called "z3types" but it doesn't seem to make any difference

What is the SMT-LIB equivalent of the MkEnumSort API call?

thanks

P.S. I have tried with RELEVANCY set to both 1 and 2 and I still get the warning about relevancy (CASE_SPLIT is set to 3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 (declare-datatypes () ((T@T (a) (b) (c)))
```

There is a tutorial with more details: http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorialcontent/guide#h27

Answer (score 0):

Use this for SMTLib v2:

```
(declare-datatypes ((T@T 0)) (((a) (b) (c))))
```

where `T@T` is the name of your type, and `a, b, c` its possible values.